# Multiple Columns to Row with respective values

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot, cross-apply

Trying to bring multiple columns into rows. The intended result is

[image]

Here's sample data with what I tried. I am open to unpivot as well if that's faster overall. The full data has 15 AttributeID, AttributeData columns.

```
DROP TABLE Attribute;

CREATE TABLE Attribute 
(
        Producttitle varchar(200),  
        AttributeID_1 varchar(50),  
        AttributeData_1 varchar(50), 
        AttributeID_2   varchar(50),
        AttributeData_2 varchar(50),
        AttributeID_3 varchar(50),  
        AttributeData_3 varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO Attribute 
VALUES ('title1', '3145', 'Specific', '30', 'Yes', '40', 'Pink')

INSERT INTO Attribute 
VALUES ('title2', '17', 'Stainless', '19', 'smoke', '19', 'Something');

SELECT
    Producttitle, 
    [AttributeID],
    [AttributeData] 
FROM
    Attribute
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 'Indicator1', [AttributeID_1] UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Indicator2', [AttributeID_2] UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Indicator3', [AttributeID_3]) c (indicatorname, [AttributeID])
CROSS APPLY
    (SELECT 'Indicator1', [AttributeData_1] UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Indicator2', [AttributeData_2] UNION ALL
     SELECT 'Indicator3', [AttributeData_3]) d (indicatorname, [AttributeData]);
```

Comment: Do you already have a working solution and are you looking for a faster implementation?

Comment: I dont have a working solution yet. The result i am getting with the above query duplicates everything.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cross apply` to unpivot your dataset. It is much simpler with `values()`:

```
select a.title, x.*
from attribute a
cross apply (values
    (a.attributeId_1, a.attributeData_1),
    (a.attributeId_2, a.attributeData_2),
    (a.attributeId_3, a.attributeData_3)
) as x(attributeId, attributeData)
```

Note that this works because the two groups of columns have consistent data types - otherwise additional casting would be required.

Answer (score 0):

GMB's solution is really cool, but basic unions will also work:

```
SELECT Producttitle, AttributeID_1 AttributeID, AttributeData_1 AttributeData
from attribute
union
SELECT Producttitle, AttributeID_2 AttributeID, AttributeData_2 AttributeData
from attribute
union
SELECT Producttitle, AttributeID_3 AttributeID, AttributeData_3 AttributeData
from attribute
```